# Stored procedure that calls a column with bit variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, web-applications

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the following stored procedure.

```
create procedure "abc.PersonReports"
    @PersonId int,
    @Approved bit = null
    ... 
    select 
       ID 'Id',
       StaffID 'Id',
       isnull(Approved, 0) 'Approved',
    ...
```

I use the following method to call the procedure:

```
PersonReports = this.personService.GetPersonReports(id, personId, Approved = false)
```

When I look at the column 'Approved' in the database, it has values of 'null', 0 and 1. These are stated as bit variables. Why is 'Approved' stated as bit = null in the procedure, and what does `isnull(Approved, 0)` mean? Basically I am trying to alter this procedure to call all rows with the column 'Approved' having the value 'null'.

Comment: This doesn't look valid? You have a `]` after `'Id',`? Is this **REALLY** the SP you are using?

Comment: Not really, just a snap shot. You did answer my question though, thank you.

Comment: One more, when you declare @Approved     bit=null, what is this effectively doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you see `@SomeName` in SQL it is a variable. So `@Approved bit = null` is creating a variable and setting its value to NULL (just initialising to some default value). I am guessing the variable is then set at some other point to TRUE / FALSE or NULL. This bit of code is not shown in your snippet though so assuming in the first `......` section you have.

Then, where you have `isnull(Approved, 0)` it is saying if `Approved` is NULL then return the value 0 (FALSE) instead of NULL.

The idea being that `Approved` can either be `TRUE` or `FALSE` and treating `NULL` as `FALSE`.

This would beg the question then why allow it to be nullable in the database but that is probably beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: No, `@Approved bit = null` is not creating a variable. It's a parameter, and it's not setting the parameter to `null` unless the procedure is called without the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is 'Approved' stated as bit = null

That is a default value for the parameter. If the procedure is called without that parameter, it will use the default value instead.

> what does isnull(Approved, 0) mean?

It means that the value of the `Approved` field is selected, and if that value is `null` then the value `0` is returned instead.

> I am trying to alter this proc to call all rows with the column
>   'Approved' having the value 'null'

For that you would add a condition like this to the query:

```
where Approved is null
```

If you want to use the `@Approved` parameter for the comparison, and allow a `null` value to get all `null` values from the table, then you would use:

```
where (@Approved is null and Approved is null) or (Approved = @Approved)
```